# How to get user info from identity provider in Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Azure Mobile Apps can authenticate against identity providers such as Facebook, Google, Twitter, and Microsoft.  After logging in, the mobile client is returned a [MobileServiceUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceuser.aspx) object.  That object contains no profile information from the identity provider such as a Twitter screen name, Facebook name, etc.

How can I get that information?  I'm specifically interested in a Twitter screen name, aka handle.

I'm aware of a blog post called [Getting user information on Azure Mobile Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/10/24/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services/).  However, it covers the JavaScript backend, not the .NET backend which I use.  Also, a simple solution only involving the mobile client and not the backend would be preferable.

If anyone from the Azure team reads this, I'd love to see `MobileServiceUser` include profile info just like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a HTTP GET of the /.auth/me endpoint submitting the MobileServiceUser.mobileServicesAuthenticationToken as a header named X-ZUMO-AUTH.

This will return a JSON blob that you can decode for the user information.

And I do work for Azure - understand the request.  Please post on the Azure Mobile Apps UserVoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-apps

Comment: Yes it is.  It's making it's way into all the HOWTO documentation on the Azure site.  Start here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/#auth-getinfo (I know that isn't ASP.NET yet - topics are continually updated)